# Aspect-Oriented Programming in C -> Function library?

Tags: function, compiler-errors, aop, aspect

I'm learning about AOP in C, using aspeCt as a compiler. The problem I'm having is that when I'm compiling, I keep getting the error `line 2 error--1: syntax error near token ''` from my .acc file.

I'm assuming that this is because of the before function in my .acc file. Is there a library that I should be importing? Or am I completely wrong here? Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

before():execution(int main()) {

printf("Before test successful!\n");

}

after(): execution(int main()) {

printf("world!\n");

}
```

Comment: This isn't C. Please keep the [c] tag out of aspeCt-related questions, in the future.

Comment: The .mc file is written in C, and it does affect this question, as AOP is mostly used in Java. I'll know for next time though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it, I had to compile with gcc first, save those files as .acc and .mc files, and then compile those with ACC, then compile them together AGAIN with gcc. Run with ./a.out, done.